# Run a simple C sample on Intel Edison

Tags: c, azure, cmake, iot, intel-edison

I am trying to connect a intel Edison to IOT hub as to documentation on Azure at Git

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/26e81a7a3358815bfee9553678f546ffe6f3d3ce/c/doc/run_sample_on_intel_edison.md

it says to

**Navigate to: ~/cmake/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_amqp**

and

**./iothub_client_samples_iothub_client_sample_amqp**

but this folder have ***nothing to run***

I found a .c file of it in  azure-iot-sdks/c/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_amqp

but it says I don't have permission , and I try it with gcc command but it says :

```
gcc ./iothub_client_sample_amqp.cthub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_amqp#
./iothub_client_sample_amqp.c:7:27: fatal error: iothub_client.h: No such file or directory
 #include "iothub_client.h"
                       ^
 compilation terminated.
cd \@pe3iot:~/azure-iot-sdks/c/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_amqp#
```

but in cmaker folder, I have iothub client folder , I have run

$ ./build_proton.sh

$ ./build.sh

*successfully and copy libqpid-proton.so.2 to lib* ,

my cmaker

**root@pe3iot:~# cmake --version
 cmake version 3.4.0**

gcc:

**root@pe3iot:~# gcc --version
 gcc (GCC) 4.9.1**

have tried Updated instructions too at

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/pull/212/files?short_path=af74a54

make all file changes it says but I was unable to run "make -f makefile.linux" with error

make: makefile.linux: No such file or directory
 make: *** No rule to make target 'makefile.linux'.  Stop.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `gcc ./iothub_client_sample_amqp.cthub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_amqp#
./iothub_client_sample_amqp.c:7:27: fatal error: iothub_client.h: No such file or directory
 #include "iothub_client.h"`
Probably, the error is here because gcc is looking for iothub_client.h in your current folder, but not it folder, in which file being compiled is located. Try to navigate to folder containing c file first and then compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, and reported the issue on azure-iot-sdks Github https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/353.

Reason for this:

> Intel Edison has older Git version installed which doesn't support
>   submodules. Our C SDK uses submodules for each protocol implementation
>   and because of those submodules were not exist the build script failed

Solution for this is to cross-compile Azure IoT SDK on Linux OS, which you can refer ashokkhurana's solution on https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/435.

Hope this helps.